# WSO2 ESB/Apache Synapse/VFS execute exe,jar,etc

Tags: apache, wso2, apache-synapse, apache-commons-vfs

Is there any way in WSO2 ESB or Synapse or VFS to execute an exe application, or command prompt, jar, or anything else??

I googling it for a while now but still got no clue about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a class mediator and do this with WSO2 ESB... You can write your own class mediator with the necessary functionalities and use it... Please see [1] to get to know about how to write class mediators.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator

Regards

Mohan

Comment: Thanks for the answer..it really work :) but now i got another problem, it just invoke the execute command once (only when the service run for the first time), how can i make it work everytime the service run again?